# Kernel Sources for Android 4.0 - Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source, android-kernel

I have downloaded Android 4.0 sources as per the instructions given in
the following link : http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

I have downloaded the sources successfully without any issues. However,
I did not find the kernel sources in it. Later I found that there are
kernel sources available at the following link.

source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html

However, these sources are device specific except the
following :

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git
```

Am I correct?

Actually, I have my own board with ARM 926 EJ processor which is
working fine with 2.6.10 kernel version and it is up and running with
this kernel version.

My idea is to port the Android 4.0/earlier versions on to this board.
My idea is as follows.

1. I will take the latest kernel which is used for Android 4.0 and add
   my patches from 2.6.10 to the latest android kernel and boot it.
2. Then, I will add the Android user space sources and try to boot
   Android from my board.

Questions: Which kernel sources shall I use i.e. from kernel.org or
above common.git? Is Android 4.0 based on 2.6.29 kernel version?

Please let me know, if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

No, ICS is based on Linux kernel 3.0.1.

You should be right with `$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git`

My source: http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html

Comment: Thanks. You mean there is a difference between common.git and kernel.org 3.0.1 kernel. I guess, the differences are related to binder, ashmem etc. I heard that these binder and other utilities are added to the main kernel at kernel.org in 3.3 version on wards. Am I correct?